# Would like insight as to why pandas truncate does not accept Period object as variable?

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to truncate a pandas Series but am surprised that the function does not take a pd.Period as an argument.

The following code does not work.

```py
pdi = pd.PeriodIndex([pd.Period('2017-09-01'),pd.Period('2017-09-02'),pd.Period('2017-09-03')])

ser = pd.Series([1,2,3], index=pdi)

ser.truncate(before=pd.Period("2017-09-03"))


TypeError: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period'> is not convertible to datetime
```

This suggests to me that PeriodIndex is just an overlay on an underlying DatetimeIndex as opposed to being implemented directly. Still trying to wrap my head around pandas (a great library!) but this seems like a design problem and would kindly like some insight from someone more knowledgeable. As a user, just hoping for a better understanding as it will help me with how I am approaching future problems.

Anyways, the workaround is simple but conceptually messy in my opinion.

```py
ser.truncate(before=str(pd.Period("2017-09-03")))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: truncate only accepts types `int`, `float`, `date` or `string` as arguments to before and after. Can't you just use `ser.truncate(before="2017-09-03")` ?

Comment: Yes, that works as well but I just find it strange that you cannot use a PeriodIndex to truncate a pandas Series with an index of type PeriodIndex. I should probably remove this question as it is more philosophical than technical I suppose.